# Accessing and modifying 2D dynamically allocated arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-memory-allocation, c-strings

I'm trying to create a 2D array of c-strings (for a specific school exercise; I'm forced to use c-strings for practice) using dynamic memory allocation. However, it seems that when accessing and writing to the second index of the array (second sub-array), the actual memory location that's used is the same of the first index.

The code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main()
{
int n_names; std::string current; const int SPACE_FOR_EACH_NAME = 100;
std::cout << "How many names to input? "; std::cin >> n_names; std::cin.ignore();

//dynamically allocate a multi-dimensional array
char** names;
names = new char* [n_names];
for (int i = 0; i < n_names; i++)
    names[i] = new char[SPACE_FOR_EACH_NAME];

int count = 0;
while (count < n_names) {
    std::cout << "Name " << ++count << ": ";
    std::getline(std::cin, current);
    names[count-1] = (char*) current.c_str(); //THE TROUBLE SEEMS TO BE HERE
}

for (int i = 0; i < n_names; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < SPACE_FOR_EACH_NAME; ++j) {
        if (names[i][j] == '\0') break; //termination of the current name
        std::cout << names[i][j];
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}

//free allocated memory
for (int i = 0; i < n_names; ++i)
    delete[] names[i];
delete[] names;
}
```

What the debugger shows when modifying the 'names' array (consider user inputs 2 names):

```
+       names[count-1]  0x00affbe8 "dude"   char * //here count is 1
+       names[count-1]  0x00affbe8 "noice"  char * //here count is 2
```

And the console just prints "noice" twice.
What's wrong?

Comment: *I'm forced to use c-strings for practice)* -- Yet your code uses a `std::string` for input, and in addition, using `std::string` functions such as `c_str()`.  Thus the assignment can't make up its mind what to use, `std::string` or char arrays and pointers.

Comment: Should I use a loop with std::cin.get() and try to implement with c-strings? I'm very new to c++ and programming in general.

Comment: Well, the restrictions placed on you (according to your post) means that you shouldn't use `std::string` anywhere.  It's a stupid restriction in this day and age of C++ (`std::string` is over 20 years old now).  Maybe you should use a simple `char` array for input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of `current.c_str()` should never be stored for any length of time. Doing so is undefined behaviour, but it is likely, as here that that memory pointed to will be reused.

You put the char* from `current.c_str()` into `names[0]`, then you put a new value into `current` and put `current.c_str()` into `names[1]`. But because you have changed `current` you also change `names[0]`.

Also, in both cases, you are discarding the pointer you already created with `names[i] = new char[SPACE_FOR_EACH_NAME];`

This allocates a block of memory and puts it's address into `names[0]` (`0` as a specific example). The next thing that happens with `names[0]` is `names[0] = (char*) current.c_str();` which puts a different address into the variable. The address returned from the `new` is lost completely, causing a memory leak.

Instead of

```
names[count-1] = (char*) current.c_str();
```

try

```
std::strcpy(names[count-1],current.c_str())
```

Comment: I don't know if the OP used `std::string` by mistake, since according to the OP, only char arrays and pointers should be used.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'm not in the business of reading the OP's mind, just fixing their code.

Comment: I didn't read the OP's mind, just their post -- *I'm forced to use c-strings for practice* -- .  Is it not reasonable to conclude that `std::string` is restricted, given the assignment that was described by the OP?

Comment: strcpy is not part of std namespace. If you need to use strcpy, you need to include <cstring>

Comment: @kadina Yes, it needs to include <cstring> but <cstring> gives you strcpy etc. in the std namespace.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I don't want to get into a silly debate. Clearly it's restricted, we just don't know *how* restricted, since we can't see the actual definition of the exercise.

Comment: @JasperKent could you elaborate what do you mean by discarding the pointer I've already created?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie it's just an informal exercise worksheet. In this particular exercise the teacher asks us to use c-strings, I just went ahead and used an std::string to try to simplify the input

Comment: @BMendes I've added an explanation to my answer.

Comment: @BMendes -- FYI, the code will break if there are more than 100 characters in the string, since `std::string` can hold any amount of characters, and that is even with the `strcpy` fix.  Are you sure your teacher is not checking for subtle uses of `std::string`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie the teacher won't check this. However I do agree that I should apply the restrictions to all my code. I will remove the std::string and work only with pointers and arrays

Comment: @JasperKent Thank you.

Comment: @BMendes If you're happy, do mark that as a correct answer.